# How pass parameters to Vuex actions from Nuxt component

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js

i'm using Nuxt.js and Vuex, i worried how pass to parameters from component to vuex in nuxt.

**Component:**

```
<div v-for="item in items" @click="getDetails(item)">
    {{item.name}}
</div>

 export default {
        methods: {
            voteDetail(item) {
                this.$store.dispatch('voteDetail');
            }
        }
    }
```

**In Vuex store:**

```
async voteDetail(item) {
     console.log(item)
     }
```

here is something goes wrong :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you need to pass it into your action. How would it know that u pass item if u dont pass it into argument call?

```
this.$store.dispatch('voteDetail', item);
```

And also in your action first argument is a context, not item. Please read [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions)

```
async voteDetail(context, item) {
     console.log(item)
     }
```

Comment: but its return me this when i console.log {dispatch: ƒ, commit: ƒ, getters: {…}, state: {…}, rootGetters: {…}, …}
commit: ƒ boundCommit(type, payload, options)
dispatch: ƒ boundDispatch(type, payload)
getters: {…}
rootGetters: {…}
rootState: {…}
state: {…}